# Unable to connect to database from ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sql-server, arccatalog

I am trying to connect to SQL Server database from  ArcMap from the same instance. I am able to connect one database; to another database I am unable to connect.

I am getting this error while connecting:

> Failed to connect to specified server. Do you want to
>   proceed? Operation failed.

What might be wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify whether you are able to connect to another **database** in the same **server**, or able to connect to a different **server** from the same **client**.

Comment: Do you have arcsde installed???

Comment: @saviour123 It is not necessary for an enterprise geodatabase to be enabled for a Desktop client to connect. It hasn't been possible to install ArcSDE in a long, long time.

Comment: It's been years since I last used SQL Server, but I expect you still need to grant logins access to databases and set up user-schema mappings before connection is possible. You should always troubleshoot connection issues from a Microsoft client if the Esri client isn't able to connect.

Comment: do you have a user granted access for the DB server side?

Comment: @Joe yes i have access to DB server.i have arcmap and SQL Server installed on same machine

Comment: @vithika Does your user actually have database permissions on that database?  Are both databases (the one you can access and the one you can't) on the same server?  Have you tried to connect as the DBO or equivalent user?  Please **[edit]** your question to include any clarification or extra information in response to comments.

Comment: is the DB accepting new connections?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of these points:

1. Have you installed SQL Server compatiable version.  If not please make sure that you have compatiable sql server client installed.
2. Have you recently restored you SDE database into another database. If that's the case then there is conflict between the configuration of SDE generated schema, as it will hold the name of previous database but your current new database name is Changed.
3. Normally, these types of errors occur, if there is something wrong with the ArcSDE schema of sql server database.